# How to save files to Documents folder on Hololens?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, uwp, hololens

I want to save some persistent JSON files on Hololens. They need to persist across builds of application so `Application.persistentDataPath` doesn't work. I chose to Documents because it makes the most sense. There is no Downloads folder on Hololens.

Here's what I've tried so far:

I have read the [App Capability Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/app-capability-declarations#restricted-capability-list) and manually added the `<uap:Capability Name="documentsLibrary"/>` to the `Package.appxmanifest` to the file.

I also added the `xmlns:rescap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities"` namespace. But I get the following warning:

```
The element 'Capabilities' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10' has invalid child element 'Capability' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities'. List of possible elements expected: 'DeviceCapability' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10'. Ad-Hoc Localz D:\Repositories\ad-hoc-localization\_build\Ad-Hoc Localz\Package.appxmanifest 37
```

and the following error on build:

```
Error APPX0501 Validation error. error C00CE014: App manifest validation error: The app manifest must be valid as per schema: Line 45, Column 6, Reason: Element '{http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10}Capability' is unexpected according to content model of parent element '{http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10}Capabilities'. Expecting: {http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10}DeviceCapability. Ad-Hoc Localz D:\Repositories\ad-hoc-localization_build\build\bin\Win32\Master\AppxManifest.xml 1
```

It also says that I need to specify file type I used [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/schemas/appxpackage/how-to-specify-extension-points-in-a-package-manifest) to add that manually to manifest. But I get the same warning i.e. invalid child element. I do not see a GUI based way to add like in this [image](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/getfile/733212) from [this forum](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/7ee61fd7-db6d-49a6-bda4-701105a500e7/uwpcant-access-documents-library-in-universal-windows-app?forum=wpdevelop)

**So how do I build an application that has access to Documents folder on Hololens?**

In the code I'm using `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)` to get path to documents but in code snippet they show that it should be `KnownFolders.DocumentsLibrary`. **Is the `Environment` not valid namespace on UWP?**

[Link to the whole manifest.](https://gist.github.com/lordlycastle/e583883db42091a414ce8e3fdc10d7f0)

Comment: It looks like some other folks have experienced issues similar to this due to [visual studio problem](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/42962/validation-error-error-c00ce014-app-manifest-valid.html).

Comment: It might be worth updating visual studio. It might also be that you need to [reorder your capabilities](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/8efde534-f84a-48d7-9dd5-fec5043a894c/uwphow-to-use-a-restricted-capability-?forum=wpdevelop) so that the rescap capabilities are declared after the uap capabilities.

Comment: As chrisfromwork says, you may need to update the version of Visual Studio. I recommend that you build your app using the latest Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: @chrisfromwork I already am using 2019 and don't see any further updates in the VS installer. And the documentLibrary capability was added last so was after any other. And in the documentation linked above the it's in `uap` namespace not `rescap`; but at the start of the main section it says to use `rescap`.... yep. Anyways I've tried both and lead to exact same results.

Comment: We might be able to provide more help if we can see the whole manifest. If it's possible, it may be worth sharing. I attempted to recreate a manifest with a new rescap capability for visual studio 2017 15.9.14 and wasn't able to hit these issues. Do you know what version of visual studio you are using (You can find this under Help -> About Microsoft Visual Studio).

Comment: @chrisfromwork I've added a link to the package manifest and the VS version info. Can you share your package manifest? I got one from a colleague but that was in the same format as linked above.

Comment: @user14492 Hi, maybe you can try adding a file type association to your program. Because DocumentsLibrary filters the content in the Documents folder based on the type of associated file you are currently applying.

Comment: @RichardZhang-MSFT I've tried that. If you look at the linked appx manifest you'll see what I tried to add; it's commented out. It gives the exact same warning ie invalid child element.

Comment: @user14492 Hi, I tested it and observed a very interesting phenomenon. You can try to put `DeviceCapability` to the end, which may work. I tested it locally and found that when `DeviceCapability` is in front of `uap:Capability`, the build will failed, and the below it is generated successfully.

Answer (score 2):

1. Don't use

xmlns:rescap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities" because DocumentLibrary capability is in uap namespace. add document capability like below

```
<Capabilities>  
    <Capability Name="internetClientServer"/>
   <Capability Name="internetClient"/>
   <uap:Capability Name="documentsLibrary"/>
  <DeviceCapability Name="microphone"/>  
</Capabilities>
```

now you should not get warning.

2. Use below lines of code to create and get file in Document folder

   ```
    IReadOnlyList<Windows.Storage.StorageFile> 
    file=awaitKnownFolders.DocumentsLibrary.CreateFileAsync("FileName");

    IReadOnlyList<Windows.Storage.StorageFile> 
    file=awaitKnownFolders.DocumentsLibrary.GetFileAsync("filename")
   ```